# Cloning and appending element with jquery turn live-aria off sometimes

Tags: jquery, slider, webflow, aria-live

I have the following problem and would appreciate your help :) Excuse my "deepL" English :)

I am using ajax to retrieve the paths of images on my database to create a dynamic image gallery with the result. For this purpose a for-loop is run x times depending on the number of images. Within one run a slide shall be cloned and added. Afterwards, the image on the slide is to be refilled accordingly using the "src" attribute.

JS Code:

```
function show_anbieter_profilbilder(){
    var sessionID = localStorage.getItem("SE_session_ID");  
    if (sessionID != null){  
        var postData={"contentID":6,"sessionID":sessionID};
        var dataString= JSON.stringify(postData);       
        ajaks(myCallback, dataString, "http://localhost/Login/wf_loadContent.php");             
        function myCallback(result){            
            var Daten = result;                     
            for(i=0; i<Daten.length; i++){
                var Bildpfad = Daten[i][0];
                var Bildstatus = Daten[i][1];
                var source = "http://localhost/Login/" + Bildpfad;
                if(Bildstatus == 1){    
                    $('#anbieter_profilbildgallerie_bild').attr('src', source);                             
                }
                var anz = Daten.length +1;
                $('#anbieter_profilbildergallerie_slide').attr('aria-label', "1 of " + anz);
                $('.w-slider-aria-label').attr('aria-live', "polite");
                $newslide = $('#anbieter_profilbildergallerie_slide').clone().insertBefore('#anbieter_profilbildergallerie_mask .w-slider-aria-label:last-child');  
                $newslide.attr('id', i);
                var pos = i+2;
                $('#' + i).attr('aria-label', pos + " of " + anz);
                $('#' + i).children().children().attr('src', source); 
            }  
        }
    }   
}
```

php Code:

```
    case 6:
        $query = "SELECT Bild, Aktiv FROM profilbilder WHERE UserID = '".$sessionID."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $bilder = [];
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            array_push($bilder, $row);
        }
        echo json_encode($bilder);
```

HTML code (excerpt):

```
<div id="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_popup" class="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_popup">
    <div id="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_popup_form" class="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_popup_form">
        <div data-delay="4000" data-animation="slide" class="slider-4 w-slider" data-autoplay="false" data-easing="ease" data-hide-arrows="false" data-disable-swipe="false" data-autoplay-limit="0" data-nav-spacing="3" data-duration="500" data-infinite="true">
            <div id="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_mask" class="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_mask w-slider-mask">
                <div id="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_slide" class="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_slide w-slide">
                    <div class="container-10 w-container">
                        <img src="mySource :P" loading="lazy" id="anbieter_profilbildgallerie_bild" alt="" class="anbieter_profilbildgallerie_bild"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-slider-arrow-left">
                <div class="icon-2 w-icon-slider-left">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-slider-arrow-right">
                <div class="icon-3 w-icon-slider-right">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="profilbildgallerie_slidenav" class="profilbildgallerie_slidenav w-slider-nav w-round">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-31 w-clearfix wf-section">
            <a href="#" class="anbieter_profilbilderdelete_button w-button">Löschen</a>
            <a href="#" class="anbieter_profilbildersetactive_button w-button">Zum Profilbild machen</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that while the element is cloned correctly, it is not added **as long as it is inside the ajax success function.** Once I place it outside, it runs as intended. Now, however, due to the asynchronous nature of the ajax, I need to place everything inside the success function (feel free to teach me better here) to know how many slides I need (since the number of images is variable).
Addition: I am working with webflow and the element to be cloned is a slide of the webflow "Slider" element. This should be added to the mask provided for it in the "Slider" element.

Eliminated error causes:

- Syntax of the clone-append is wrong: The code works outside the success function.
- ID of clone-object or append-object are not known inside the function (for whatever reason): Both objects could be styled using .css...
- Result of the ajax does not return the desired result: Has been checked, runs correctly
- Cloning and appending does not work within an ajax success function with webflow stuff: Exactly the same constellation works elsewhere! See the following code:

Working Code:

```
function show_anbieter_ausbildung(){
    var sessionID = localStorage.getItem("SE_session_ID");  
    if (sessionID != null){  
        var postData={"contentID":2,"sessionID":sessionID};
        var dataString= JSON.stringify(postData)
        ajaks(myCallback, dataString, "http://localhost/Login/wf_loadContent.php");
        function myCallback(result){
            var Daten = result;                 
            for(i=0; i<Daten.length; i++){
                var EintragsID_r = Daten[i][0];
                var Institution_r = Daten[i][1];
                var Abschluss_r = Daten[i][2];
                var Fachrichtung_r = Daten[i][3];
                var Abschlussnote_r = Daten[i][4];
                var Beginn_r = convertdate(new Date(Daten[i][5]));
                var Ende_r = convertdate(new Date(Daten[i][6]));
                var Kurzbeschreibung_r = Daten[i][7];
             
                $ausbildungitem = $('#Ausbildungitem').clone(true).appendTo('#Ausbildung_Inhalt');             
                $ausbildungitem.attr('id',"item-" + EintragsID_r);
                $ausbildungitem.show();
                $ausbildungitem.attr('draggable', "true");                      
                $ausbildungitem.children().children('.ausbildung_institution').text(Institution_r);
                $ausbildungitem.children().children('.ausbildung_abschluss').text(Abschluss_r + ", " + Fachrichtung_r + ", Abschlussnote: " + Abschlussnote_r);
                $ausbildungitem.children().children('.ausbildung_zeitraum').text(Beginn_r +" - " + Ende_r);
                $ausbildungitem.children().children('.ausbildung_kurzbeschreibung').text(Kurzbeschreibung_r);
                $ausbildungitem.children().children('.anbieter_ausbildungupdate_edit').attr('editID', EintragsID_r);
                $ausbildungitem.children().children('.anbieter_ausbildungdelete_button').attr('deleteID', EintragsID_r);                
            }
            $('#Ausbildung_Inhalt').height(140*Daten.length);       
        };                        
    };    
};
```

**Update: It works now in some cases. Here the new added elements:**

```
<div id="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_mask" class="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_mask w-slider-mask">
    <div id="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_slide" class="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_slide w-slide" aria-label="1 of 4" role="group" style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1; transition: transform 500ms ease 0s;"></div>
    <div id="0" class="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_slide w-slide" aria-label="2 of 4" role="group" style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1; transition: transform 500ms ease 0s;" aria-hidden="true"></div>
    <div id="1" class="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_slide w-slide" aria-label="3 of 4" role="group" style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1; transition: transform 500ms ease 0s;" aria-hidden="true"></div>
    <div id="2" class="anbieter_profilbildergallerie_slide w-slide" aria-label="4 of 4" role="group" style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1; transition: transform 500ms ease 0s;" aria-hidden="true"></div>
    <div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" class="w-slider-aria-label" data-wf-ignore="" aria-hidden="true">Slide 1 of 4.</div>
</div>
```

Now the problem ist, that the attribute "aria-live" is polite sometimes and sometimes it turns off (randomly?) and then the cloned elements are not shown and accessible in the slideshow. I updated my js code as well to set the appended elements before the slider, so that the slider includes all of them. Furthermore i try to set the aria-live attribute on polite, but this is not working. (I have no clue about the aria-live).

Comment: Your sql is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: True, but not my question ;) Thank you nevertheless :)

Comment: You have not shown any HTML so it is hard to fully understand the problem - there should be no reason that you cannot append clones within the ajax callback. One thing I notice is that within the loop you call `$('#anbieter_profilbildergallerie_slide').clone(true)` which will always select the same element

Comment: Here you go, HTML is added :) Yup, there should be no reason, that's why i am so confused. I want to copy the same over and over and after copying i change the id immediately, so that's no problem.

Comment: Could it be that within `$('#Bildpfad').attr('src', source);` that there is no element with that ID and should be `$('#'+Bildpfad).attr('src', source);`? Also there is no element with id `anbieter_profilbild` that I can see

Comment: Yup thats true, fixed it, but the append before that does not work in both cases. Yes the "anbieter_profilbild" exists but not in the posted html because it affects an other element of the website and it work. I deleted it in the post, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I do not use jQuery so have no knowledge of the methods used here - `clone` is obviously very similar to `cloneNode` and `appendTo` similar to either `appendChild` or `append` but there might be vagaries in the syntax I know nothing about. You say it (the append operation) does not work - are there errors in the console? If you inspect the HTML elements on the page there are no new elements added?

Comment: Rather than cloning `live` elements within the loop have you considered using a [content template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) ? It might save having to change IDs or use IDs completely perhaps.

Comment: I updated the problem. Maybe you have experience in this "aria-live" stuff, its new to me and google is no help at all..